# Creating a Pawn that simulates physics

Tags: physics, unreal-4

I'm trying to make a Pawn that I can raycast against. Starting from the DefaultPawn object, I can't find a way to have a StaticMesh cube that simulates physics. My raycasting code works with Actors, but I'd like to apply the same feature to moving objects now.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: "static" in the context of physics usually means "does not move or rotate" - so what kind of simulation is it that you need from a static cube?

Comment: I see why this is confusing, I wrote static cube because I am using static meshes. For now I am willing to swap the positions and velocities of my character and a selected pawn. I tested on actors for the positions, but I guess I need pawns for the velocity part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a DefaultPawn object allows to have a Pawn with physics. In order to Raytrace against Pawns, it is necessary to specify `ECollisionChannel::ECC_Pawn` when calling `LineTraceSingleByObjectType`.